# Building dashboards in django

Tags: django, dashboard

I have a django app and I would like to display some graphical data visualization to my users.  I am looking for an easy-to-use package that would allow me to add graphs and widgets.

The kind of widget I want to build is a kind of speedometer dial that is red at one end and green at the other.   As a user completes their job over the day, the graphic/widget adjusts itself.  The dial moves from red to green.

I also want an S-curve graphic that shows the cumulative amount of work accomplished against planned.  That is kind of an x/y line plot.

My question are:  How easy is this to implement?   Are there any add-ins libraries or packages that do this already?   I am trying to keep my entire application open-source.  I've seen a couple subscription services that do this type of thing, but I can't stomach the cost.

I don't mind using ajax or jquery to implement such a thing, but I would like the most elegant and maintainable solution.

Any advice or examples on how to tackle this project?

Answer (score 6):

As first, see the following grid (https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/dashboard-applications/) on djangopackages.

Not sure if that's exactly what's asked for, but you might take a look at `django-dash` (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-dash).

It allows each user to make his own dashboard (from plugins available). Those dashboards can be made public.

Some screenshots (http://pythonhosted.org/django-dash/#screenshots).

It's modular and plugin based, so you need to make a plugin and widgets for every specific feature (in this particular case - the speedometer plugin and widgets for it). Each plugin/widget can include own JS/CSS when being rendered.

See the following chart usage examples:

- D3.js integration examples (https://github.com/barseghyanartur/django-dash/tree/master/example/example/d3_samples).
- Polychart2.js integration example (https://github.com/barseghyanartur/django-dash/blob/master/example/example/bar/).

Answer (score 5):

There are lots of good javascript libraries these days, but all require some effort to learn how to use.  I have not found one that really is easy to use, I guess because everyone wants something different.  My general experience has been the more effort you put into learning them, the more you get out.

Google has gauges: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/gauge.html
Also

- http://www.flotcharts.org/
- http://philogb.github.com/jit/
- http://www.highcharts.com/
- http://www.jqplot.com/

Or really take control:
http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/

Comment: Google also provides some pretty good graphs and the like in their AJAX API:  http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#annotated_time_line

Comment: Yes and the code playground makes it easier to customise too!

Comment: Update: check out D3.js if you haven't come across it already.

Answer (score 2):

protovis is no longer under active development, but they started a new poject: http://d3js.org/

Answer (score 0):

You may choose from these packages:
https://www.djangopackages.com/search/?q=dash